# Como sincronizar Javascript y una aplicación de Windows en C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, windows-forms

Tengo una plataforma creada en visual `C#`, y en ella se guarda la información de varios pacientes y está accede a diversos hardware. Debido a que se está implementando esta misma plataforma pero versión web y se necesita controlar los equipos, hay un problema. La plataforma está en un servidor remoto y la detección de hardware está hecha con `C#`.

La pregunta sería, cómo hacer que la plataforma web abriera o se sincronizara con la aplicación de `C#` y pudieran enviarse datos entre ellas.

Sé que se puede porque lo vi en la página de Dell, ellos te hacen descargar un software y al instalarlo en tu máquina la plataforma web de Dell accede a toda la configuración de tu equipo y te da un reporte del software y hardware, en la misma pestaña sin abrir una nueva ni nada parecido.

Comment: Puedes crear un servicio REST desde el que controles los dispositivos hardware y éste se constituya como fuente de datos y controlador de hardware tanto para tu plataforma web como para la plataforma que tienes en C#

Comment: Habia pensado en eso pero, por usabilidad, quisiera que el mismo formulario web aparezca un loading y que mientras no termine el proceso de escritorio no desaparezca y cuando termine que en el mismo formulario cargue la informacion. No se como hacer eso. Estaba pensando algo como esto => http://www.dell.com/support/home/co/es/codhs1/products?~ck=mn